# How to connect ArgoCD with Crossplane created clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, argo

I have the ArgoCD server running and wanna define a `Cluster` without the CLI. I wanna practice **GitOps**, so I wanna declare my ArgoCD-cluster config in Git.

In the CLI I could do: `argocd cluster add` but how to do that with a **Kubernetes manifest**?

I didn't found how to create that `Cluster` declarative. I found how to create `Repositories`, and `Projects`, but nothing for something like `kind: cluster`.

I am creating my clusters with `Crossplane` (Crossplane creates clusters by k8s manifests). Crossplane saves the `kubeconfig` of it's created clusters in `Secret`s files, which looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cluster-details-my-cluster
  namespace: default
  uid: 50c7acab-3214-437c-9527-e66f1d563409
  resourceVersion: '12868'
  creationTimestamp: '2022-01-06T19:03:09Z'
  managedFields:
    - manager: crossplane-civo-provider
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2022-01-06T19:03:09Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:data:
          .: {}
          f:kubeconfig: {}
        f:type: {}
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/cluster-details-my-cluster
data:
  kubeconfig: >-
    YXBpVmVyc2lvbjogdjEKY2x1c3RlcnM6Ci0gY2x1c3RlcjoKICAgIGNlcnRpZmljYXRlLWF1dGhvcml0eS1kYXRhOiBMUzB0TFMxQ1JVZEpUaUJEUlZKVVNVWkpRMEZVUlMwdExTMHRDazFKU1VKbFJFTkRRVkl5WjBGM1NVSkJaMGxDUVVSQlMwSm5aM0ZvYTJwUFVGRlJSRUZxUVdwTlUwVjNTSGRaUkZaUlVVUkVRbWh5VFROTmRHTXlWbmtLWkcxV2VVeFhUbWhSUkVVeVRrUkZNRTlVVlROT1ZFbDNTR2hqVGsxcVNYZE5WRUV5VFZScmQwMXFUWGxYYUdOT1RYcEpkMDFVUVRCTlZHdDNUV3BOZVFwWGFrRnFUVk5_SHORTENED
type: Opaque
```

The `data.kubeconfig` content is a regular bas64 encoded `kubeconfig`, so it's easy to decode, like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUJlRENDQVIyZ0F3SUJBZ0lCQURBS0JnZ3Foa2pPUFFRREFqQWpNU0V3SHd_SHORTENED
    server: https://MY.IP.TO.K8S:6443
  name: my-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: my-cluster
    user: my-cluster
  name: my-cluster
current-context: my-cluster
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: my-cluster
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUJrVENDQVRlZ0F3SUJBZ0lJQS9adEZFT1Avcnd3Q2dZSUtvWkl6ajBFQXdJd0l6RWhNQjhHQTFVRUF3d1kKYXpOekxXTnNhV1Z1ZEMxallVQXhOalF4TkRrMU56VXlNQjRYRFRJeU1ERXdOakU1TURJek1sb1hEVEl6TURFdwpOakU1TURJek1sb3dNREVYT_SHORTENED
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBFQyBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCk1IY0NBUUVFSUpJNlVhTDlLem9yL1VpdzlXK1NNUTAxV1BES2ZIK_SHORTENED
```

Do I really need a manually intervention and have to break GitOps practice? Only to tell ArgoCD where my clusters and their configs are? The config is already in the cluster.

```
k get secret cluster-details-my-cluster
NAME                                 TYPE     DATA   AGE
cluster-details-my-cluster   Opaque   1      158m
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: If you are already using Crossplane, there is an [ArgoCD Provider[][0] for it that it helps in creating Clusters, Projects and Repositories through yaml manifests

[0]: https://marketplace.upbound.io/providers/crossplane-contrib/provider-argocd/v0.2.0

I'm still strugling to make it work, and I've found little documentation ... but I believe is the way to go

Comment: Hi @matus, thank you. I know this plugin. the very last step is to autmate the connection. I modified with my extremly rare Go knowledge an existent repo: https://github.com/exocode/crossargo-sync. The most crucial step is that the kubeconfig is not created and picked up automatically by ArgoCD. I had some discussions on GitHub. Normally it would be a really small invasive change, but somehow its not realized: https://github.com/crossplane-contrib/provider-argocd/issues?q=is%3Aissue+author%3A%40me